# How to measure building and lauch time

Tags: visual-studio, sitefinity

I'm developing a Sitefinity application and it is quite slow to launch it. It can go from 3 to more than 10 minutes.

So I would like to know if there is any tool to measure the time the visual studio spends launching an application, see graphics, and other data.

I'm using visual studio community edition 2013

Comment: It is definitely too much. Is the database on your local dev environment?

Comment: the database is in other machine, but the development is local yes  :)

Comment: I would like to use it to test know how much of the time I'm waiting to make a report and how much I'am developing

Comment: what I meant is that it may be due to a slow connection between your local machine and the remote DB server. Have you enabled the Diagnostics module - it can give you some insights as to what queries are slowest, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was quite unexpected but the problem was on the charger that was given to me. It hadn't enough power, so it took much more time to charge and the whole computer were slower including (launching the application). If I used the laptop without the charger(battery only) the launching was much faster. So I changed the charger and now it takes 1 to 3 minutes lanching sitefinity.

thank you for the suggestions though.

Comment: That's great. However, your answer doesn't correspond to the initial question. You might want to rephrase the question or accept my answer instead. The goal is this thread to be useful to someone else as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JustTrace](http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx) and profile the w3wp process that Sitefinity starts in your IIS (provided that you have hosted your Sitefinity application in IIS).

Alternatively, if the problem is not reproducible on your local environment, you can try with [NewRelic](https://newrelic.com/). I've foudn some pretty good insights while debugging performance problems using it.